# MySQL Error #1932 table doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I use xampp Controll panel v3.2.2

A few days earlier I changed the table names from existing tables. For example from "`tbl_name_peteroschmitz_soccer`" into "`tbl_name_peter-schmitz_soccer`". I'm not 100% sure but I think the tables works fine and there were no problems.

Today I click on a tablename in PHPMyAdmin and get an error

> "#1932 table 'tbl_name_peter-schmitz_soccer' doesn't exist in engine"

Another things is that before I create a new database with tables who have the same names as in the other database to test something. Then I delete this test database with all tables.

After that I clicked on a tablename in PHPMyAdmin and get an error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `tbl_name_peter-schmitz_soccer` the hyphen is the problem. MySQL thinks you want to do math, as in `tbl_name_peter MINUS schmitz_soccer`. You didn't show your code, so this stands to be the solution here since you did tag as PHP and no idea why you did with no code to support the question.

Comment: There is no code, i work in phpmyadmin, click on a table and get the error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- in this case MySQL would complain about `'tbl_name_peter'` not existing in the database. Phpmyadmin does know how to escape a table name.

Comment: @Shadow No idea at this point. The OP originally tagged as "php", so I assumed they were not escaping the table name. Maybe they chose the wrong database, I don't know; question's unclear (to me).

Comment: How exactly did you change the name in the first place?